# How to get user id in ruby on rails app views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In laravel I am use to having

```
Auth::user()->id
```

which I can reference for setting up data-id's or something in views.  I am working in a ruby on rails app and cannot for the life of me find an answer to how to achieve this in rails.  I found a lot of answers talking about current_user but I cannot get any data in the view.

To be clear what I am try to set up exactly is

```
<a href="/chapters/<%= chapter.id%>" data-user-id="<%= @current_user.id %>"> Enroll </a>
```

Here the "current_user.id" would be that users id. With the code above (and any variation of it I can think of) I am getting nothing, no errors but no data either. Do I really have to set this up in every controller method to access it somehow?  Does anyone have a solution to this that they can point me towards?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: what are you using for authentication? are you using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise?

Comment: No I was working off of the Hartl Ruby on rails tutorial.

Comment: You need a gem like devise to have a `current_user`. Maybe you can implement your own but I think It's like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: is the logged user what you want, right?

Comment: Ya information for the logged in user

Comment: I suggest you to use devise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to access any instance variable in a view, you need to define it first (either in a controller or in the view).

Depending on how you have auth set up, you probably have a `current_user` method somewhere.

It could be defined in ApplicationController (which has functionality shared by all controllers);

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    User.find_by id: session["current_user_id"]
    # or whatever
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

The `helper_method` line makes it accessible in your views, so you can write `<%= current_user.id %>`.

You could also write some code so that the `@current_user` instance variable is available in all your views:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :define_current_user
  def define_current_user
    @current_user = current_user # call the 'current_user' method defined elsewhere
  end
end
```

Comment: I am curious why this got marked down, is it a bad answer in some way?

Comment: I guess it was due to the implementation of `current_user`. You accesses database each time `current_user` is called. P.S. It wasn't me who voted down your answer.

Comment: Great answer, but some corrections for posterity 1. Do not go the way of `define_current_user`, it's counter-productive in my opinion. If you want to assign `@current_user`, change the current_user method to this: `def current_user; @current_user ||= User.find(session['current_user_id']); end`. 2. Don't use the `find_by id:` approach, calling the current_user should expose the current_user not fail silently(by returning `nil`). 3. Note that different libraries have their ways of setting the current_user, if you're using devise, you don't need to do this setting anymore